# How do I explain the large difference between page execution time and reasonable query execution time?

Tags: database, performance

I believe that one of my websites is running rather slowly.  I have done nothing different than I have on other Drupal websites that I have done that are running on different servers and that are running much faster.

Would this "slowness" be somehow described by the fact that the page takes 4 times longer to load than it does to actually execute the SQL queries?

> Page execution time was 2251.03 ms. Executed 342 queries in 477.02 milliseconds.

If you see above, you can see that it takes more than 4 times longer to execute the page than it does to actually get the data it needs to show on the page.

I have another site that is nearly identical and I have much faster load times:

> Executed 241 queries in 108.32 milliseconds. Page execution time was 1065.35 ms.

What explains the difference between the two sites, and how could I go about fixing the slow site?

Comment: Ironically, your 'faster' site has 900% time in CPU compared to the database while the slow site which only has 300%. It may be faster overall, but the massive discrepancy between database access and everything else is still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an easy calculation:

```
page_execution_time = query_time + php_time;
```

So basically you seem to do quite a lot of stuff in php.
Same basic stuff you could do

- Use some opcode cache, for example apc
- Find out what needs a lot of time using xhprof

Comment: +1 to use xhprof. It will give very comprehensive picture of page execution bottlenecks.